# CSS div nth child, bold every 2nd and 3rd text

Tags: css

How can i achieve this with :nth

- Lorem ipsum
- **Lorem ipsum**
- **Lorem ipsum**
- Lorem ipsum
- **Lorem ipsum**
- **Lorem ipsum**
- Lorem ipsum

Comment: See - http://nthmaster.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `li:nth-child(3n+2), li:nth-child(3n+3)`

```css
li:nth-child(3n+2),
li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch by a matter of seconds; upvoted.